# Bokeh layout changing and plot size incorrect after push_notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I am trying to make a somewhat complex dashboard in bokeh with several different figure objects and widgets arranged in rows and columns.

When a user interacts with the widgets, some of the plots are updated, and some remain the same. I am creating new plot objects and replacing them with layout.children[i] = x and then sending a push_notebook to update the dashboard, but this causes some of the plots to resize to the minimum canvas size.

I have created a simple example to show what I mean:

```
from numpy import random
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox, column
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button, Slider
from bokeh.io import push_notebook, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models.callbacks import CustomJS
output_notebook()
num_samples = 500
def bUpdate(var, val):
    global num_samples
    if var == "Number of Samples":
        num_samples = int(val)
        replotBottom()              
def bReCalc():
    x = [random.random() for i in range(num_samples)]
    y = [random.random() for i in range(num_samples)]
    p = figure(plot_width=COL1_W, plot_height=250)
    p.circle(x, y, color='red') 
    p.toolbar.logo = None
    layout.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[1] = p
    x = [random.random() for i in range(num_samples)]
    y = [random.random() for i in range(num_samples)]
    p2 = figure(plot_width=COL2_W, plot_height=int(COL1_W*1.8))
    p2.circle(x,y)
    layout.children[0].children[0].children[1].children[0] = p2
    push_notebook(handle=bokeh_handle)
def replotBottom():    
    x = [random.random() for i in range(num_samples)]
    y = [random.random() for i in range(num_samples)]
    p2 = figure()
    p2.circle(x,y)
    p2.plot_width=COL1_W
    p2.plot_height=COL1_W    

    x = [random.random() for i in range(num_samples)]
    y = [random.random() for i in range(num_samples)]
    p3 = figure(plot_width = COL2_W, plot_height = int(COL1_W*1.5))
    p3.circle(x,y,color='green')

    x = [random.random() for i in range(num_samples)]
    y = [random.random() for i in range(num_samples)]
    z = [random.random() for i in range(num_samples)]
    p4 = figure(plot_width = int(TOTAL_WIDTH/2-5), plot_height=COL1_W)
    p5 = figure(plot_width = int(TOTAL_WIDTH/2-5), plot_height=COL1_W)
    p4.circle(x,y)
    p5.circle(x,z)

    layout.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[3]=p2
    layout.children[0].children[0].children[1].children[1]=p3
    layout.children[0].children[1].children[0] = p4
    layout.children[0].children[1].children[1] = p5
    push_notebook(handle=bokeh_handle)

cb = CustomJS(code="""
if (IPython.notebook.kernel !== undefined) {
    var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
    cmd = "bUpdate('" + cb_obj.title + "','" + cb_obj.value + "')";
    kernel.execute(cmd, {}, {});
}
""")

cbRC = CustomJS(code="""
if (IPython.notebook.kernel !== undefined) {
    var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
    cmd = "bReCalc()";
    kernel.execute(cmd, {}, {});
}
""")

TOTAL_WIDTH = 800
COL1_W = int(0.25*TOTAL_WIDTH)-5
COL2_W = int(0.75*TOTAL_WIDTH)-5
WID_W = int(0.5*COL1_W) - 15
btnCalc = Button(label="Recalculate", callback=cbRC, width=WID_W)
sldSamples = Slider(start=20, end=1000, step=10, title="Number of Samples", callback_policy="mouseup", callback=cb, width=WID_W)

layout = row(column( row( column( btnCalc, figure(plot_width=COL1_W, plot_height=250), \
                               sldSamples, figure(plot_width=COL1_W, plot_height=COL1_W)), \
                        column( figure(plot_width=COL2_W, plot_height=int(COL1_W*1.8)), \
                               figure(plot_width=COL2_W, plot_height = int(COL1_W*1.5), sizing_mode="scale_height")) \
                      ), \
                   row(figure(plot_width = int(TOTAL_WIDTH/2-5), plot_height=COL1_W), figure(plot_width = int(TOTAL_WIDTH/2-5), plot_height=COL1_W))))
bokeh_handle = show(layout, notebook_handle=True)
```

When a user clicks the button or changes the value of the slider, some of the plots get updated and redrawn, while others get randomly resized. But, if you just call "show(layout)" in another cell, the layout displays correctly.  Anyone have any ideas for best practices for this type of thing?

==EDIT==

The same type of error occurs, even when embedding a bokeh server similar to this example: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/notebook_embed.ipynb

```
output_notebook()
def modify_doc(doc):
    num_samples = 500
    def sampChange(attr, old, new):
        global num_samples
        num_samples = int(new)    
        x = [random.random() for i in range(num_samples)]
        y = [random.random() for i in range(num_samples)]
        p2 = figure()
        p2.circle(x,y)
        p2.plot_width=COL1_W
        p2.plot_height=COL1_W    

        x = [random.random() for i in range(num_samples)]
        y = [random.random() for i in range(num_samples)]
        p3 = figure(plot_width = COL2_W, plot_height = int(COL1_W*1.5))
        p3.circle(x,y,color='green')

        x = [random.random() for i in range(num_samples)]
        y = [random.random() for i in range(num_samples)]
        z = [random.random() for i in range(num_samples)]
        p4 = figure(plot_width = int(TOTAL_WIDTH/2-5), plot_height=COL1_W)
        p5 = figure(plot_width = int(TOTAL_WIDTH/2-5), plot_height=COL1_W)
        p4.circle(x,y)
        p5.circle(x,z)

        layout.children[0].children[1] = row(p4,p5)
        layout.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[3]=p2
        layout.children[0].children[0].children[1].children[1]=p3
        #layout.children[0].children[1].children[1] = p5
        #doc.add_root(layout)
    def bReCalc():
        x = [random.random() for i in range(num_samples)]
        y = [random.random() for i in range(num_samples)]
        p = figure(plot_width=COL1_W, plot_height=250)
        p.circle(x, y, color='red') 
        p.toolbar.logo = None
        layout.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[1] = p
        x = [random.random() for i in range(num_samples)]
        y = [random.random() for i in range(num_samples)]
        p2 = figure(plot_width=COL2_W, plot_height=int(COL1_W*1.8))
        p2.circle(x,y)
        layout.children[0].children[0].children[1].children[0] = p2
        #doc.add_root(layout)
        #push_notebook(handle=bokeh_handle)

    TOTAL_WIDTH = 800
    COL1_W = int(0.25*TOTAL_WIDTH)-5
    COL2_W = int(0.75*TOTAL_WIDTH)-5
    WID_W = int(0.5*COL1_W) - 15
    btnCalc = Button(label="Recalculate", width=WID_W)
    sldSamples = Slider(start=20, end=500, step=10, title="Number of Samples", callback_policy="mouseup", width=WID_W)
    btnCalc.on_click(bReCalc)
    sldSamples.on_change('value', sampChange)
    layout = row(column( row( column( btnCalc, figure(plot_width=COL1_W, plot_height=250), \
                                   sldSamples, figure(plot_width=COL1_W, plot_height=COL1_W)), \
                            column( figure(plot_width=COL2_W, plot_height=int(COL1_W*1.8)), \
                                   figure(plot_width=COL2_W, plot_height = int(COL1_W*1.5))) \
                          ), \
                       row(figure(plot_width = int(TOTAL_WIDTH/2-5), plot_height=COL1_W), figure(plot_width = int(TOTAL_WIDTH/2-5), plot_height=COL1_W))))
    doc.add_root(layout)
    bReCalc()
    return doc

from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.application import Application
handler = FunctionHandler(modify_doc)
app = Application(handler)
show(app)
```

Comment: Python 3.6.1
Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)
IPython 5.3.0

Comment: I've tried a few different ways of doing the update including using curdoc() and deleting the root and resetting it to be my layout variable, but none of them trigger the correct redraw events for push_notebook

Comment: I would recommend embedded a real Bokeh server app in the notebook, it's going to be much more robust than anything using `push_notebook`. Some day when someone has time `push_notebook` will be re-implemented on top of an embedded sever to make it better. You can find an example here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/notebook_embed.ipynb

Comment: I tried remaking my simple example using the app method that bigreddot sent in the link, but I get the same kinds of errors using this method. Also, the application runs much slower than just using push_notebook (just updating the plots takes ~15 seconds)

Comment: Something is weird in your setup, then. When I run your app code the app initially displays instantly. Also I would say you method updating is not optimal. The best way to updated plots is not to *replace* the plot, but to update the data in an existing plot. I'd be happy to try to help advise more on this (modulo my available bandwidth) but SO is terrible for iterative, back and forth work. Please feel free to come by the public mailing list https://groups.google.com/a/anaconda.com/forum/#!forum/bokeh